# DNN difference between panes and containers (vs Wordpress)

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-8

We've obtained a client using DNN as their CMS. Basically we are a wordpress shop, so I'm trying to relate DNN to WP, as in most cases its just a problem of nomenclature (a module is a widget, a pane is a widgetized area, a theme is a theme, a skin is a layout). The only thing that's different is that DNN also has "containers". There is no equivalent in WP (or any php-based cms).

What is a container? Do panes have containers? Do modules  have containers? What is hierarchical relationship? I've added modules to panes, but I don't see how to add a container to a pane and then put a module in it. And if containers are just a way to style modules, why not just use stylesheets?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a little late, but I thought I would add this to help out the next person that comes across this: A Container is a wrapper around a module. Think of this as a skin is to a page, a container is to a module. So, for example, you can have multiple containers to chose from. Let's say that one container could have a grey background, another a blue background and another, no background. You could switch out that style on a module by switching containers. So, that way, you could have multiple modules in 1 content pane, but each could have it's own style. Another use case is, applying different layouts or maybe even different headers, such as some have an h1 as the module title, another an h2 for the title and a third removes the title completely so it doesn't even show up.

I hope this helps to add some clarification.